# Android do something when activity is shown

Tags: android

**Original question:**

A button in my app starts an activity, which needs some time to prepare classes.

To let a user know this, I start a new loading activity that starts the actual activity.

This activity needs to be shown before the actual is started.

But all methods of the Android lifecycle seem to be called before the activity is shown to the user and if I start a new activity before the activity I'm currently in is shown, it won't be shown anymore.

I tried:

- Starting the activity in another thread, but this does not work because the `startActivity(...)` seems to block the UI reload
- Waiting a few milliseconds before starting the activity, but this seems dirty

Any help is appreciated! Please tell me if using a forward activity is not the right solution!

Comment: A forwarding activity is fine but the key is making the forwarding activity as simple as possible or you will face the same problem. See this link on point 3. Splash screen with xml layout https://medium.com/swlh/splash-screen-in-android-8ab250e40190              
3 is the simplest/cleanest one but they have a lot of very cool solutions

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I did not think about that, thank you. I did not end up using this method because I want to display something that I calculate using code, but it gave me an idea, which works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for people who are searching:**

Use this code to do something when the activity is already visible:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If the activity can also turn visible shortly after your code, use Androids lifecycle methods (here probably `onResume()`):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // do something
}
```